# diagram drawing by Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I am new to Tex, below is the image I wish to redraw by Tikz. If you have any suggestions, pls, help.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You probably want to check out the section on intersections of the tikz-pgf manual to re-create this drawing.

Comment: Any news? Does received answer (which is replicate showed image perfectly) not fulfil your expectation? What you miss in it? To my opinion it deserve to be accepted!

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3):

With use of `calc` and `intersections` libraries, you can achieve this kind of thing.
[image: Train and Tunnel]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\g{2} \def\h{3} \def\j{5} \def\c{4}
        \def\r{2.3} %ratio for vertical lines
        
        \coordinate (E) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (G) at (\g,0);
        \coordinate (H) at (\h,0);
        \coordinate (J) at (\j,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (\g,\c);
        
        \draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (3.5*\g,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,\r*\c) coordinate (ct) node[above]{$ct$};
        
        \draw[name path=EC,->] (E) -- ($(E)!\r!(C)$) node[above]{$ct'$} node[sloped,above,pos=0.3]{\tiny \textit{trajectory of back end of train}};
        \draw[name path=GF] (G) --++ ($(E)!\r!(C)$) node[sloped,below,pos=0.1]{\tiny \textit{trajectory}} node[sloped,below,pos=0.4]{\tiny \textit{of front end of train}};
        \coordinate (aux1) at (ct-|H);
        \draw[name path=HF] (H) -- (aux1) node[pos=0.9,rotate=90,above,text width=2cm,align=center]{\baselineskip=0.2pt \tiny \textit{trajectory of\\tunnel entrance}\par};
        \coordinate (aux2) at (ct-|J);
        \draw[name path=JD] (J) -- (aux2) node[pos=0.2,yshift=-15pt,rotate=90,below,text width=2cm,align=center]{\baselineskip=0.2pt \tiny \textit{trajectory of\\tunnel exit}\par};
        
        \path [name intersections={of=GF and HF,by=F}];
        \path [name intersections={of=EC and HF,by=A}];
        \path [name intersections={of=GF and JD,by=D}];

        \draw[dashed] (C) -- (D) -- (A) --++ ($(D)-(C)$) coordinate (B);
        
        \draw[->] (E) -- ($(E)!2.3!(F)$) node[right]{$x'$};
        
        \foreach \p in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J} \fill (\p) circle(1pt);
        
        \node[below left] at (E) {E};
        \node[below] at (G) {G};
        \foreach \p in {A,B,C,D,F,H,J} \node[below right] at (\p) {\p};
        
        % Train and tunnel
        
        \draw (-.5,-2) -- (3.5*\g,-2);
        \fill[pattern=north east lines] (-.5,-2) rectangle (3.5*\g,-2.1);
        \draw (0,-1.8) --++ (\g,0) --++ (.2,.5) --++ (-\g,0) --cycle;
        \path (0,-1.8) --++ (\g,.5)  node[midway](train){\textit{train}};
        \draw (0.2*\g,-1.9) circle (.1) (0.8*\g,-1.9) circle (.1);
        
        \draw[dashed] (H) --++ (0,-1) (J) --++ (0,-1);
        \draw (\h,-2) rectangle (\j,-1) node[midway](tunnel){\textit{tunnel}};

        \path (train) -- (tunnel) node[pos=0.55]{$\Rightarrow$};
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```